# WSO2 API MANAGER change NOT SECURE

Tags: ssl, wso2, api-manager

I tried to change security of the pages:

- https://localhost:9443/carbon
- https://localhost:9443/devportal
- https://localhost:9443/publisher

**Not Secure** of this page for Secure
[Change this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJMRi.png)

Adidional:
I use WSO2 Api Manager Version 3.0.0

Comment: What do you mean by add SSL? SSL is already enabled in all those. And I don't see a question in your post.

Comment: I edit the post.
Thanks for comment

Answer (score 0):

This is because WSO2 products are shipped with self-singled certificates and they are being used for SSL communication.

You have to release the self-signed certificate with a CA-signed certificate or add the default self-signed certificate into your browser's trusted cert list.

Refer to the following documents to learn more.

- https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Administer/ProductSecurity/ConfiguringKeystores/configuring-keystores-in-wso2-api-manager/
- https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Administer/ProductSecurity/ConfiguringKeystores/KeystoreBasics/creating-new-keystores/